# Linear Combinations and solutions [Columnwise Description of Matrices]

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

> Let $A$ be a $5\times 3$ matrix.
>
> If $b = a_1 + a_2 = a_2 + a_3$ where $a_1, a_2, a_3$ are columns of $A$ then what can we conclude about the number of solutions of the linear system $Ax = b$?

Same Question for: when $b = a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4$

This query is from this [Book](https://d1b10bmlvqabco.cloudfront.net/attach/k45embmtszq5kl/k45ec4ewuxs71a/k5qppgehy42y/Steven_J._Leon__Linear_Algebra_with_ApplicationsPearson_2015.pdf) page number 62

I am stuck at: let $a_1=[1,0,0]$, $a_2=[0,1,0]$ and $a_3=[0,0,1]$ but upon $a_1+a_2$ and $a_2+a_3$ these are not equal. such as $[1,1,0]$ and $[0,1,1]$

Comment: What do you think? We are not here to blindly answer your homework questions, but can help you if you are stuck. It may also help to give the page number of the problem in the book so we can read the context surrounding it

Comment: i am stuck at: 
let a1=[1,0,0], a2=[0,1,0] and a3=[0,0,1]
but upon a1+a2 and a2+a3 these are not equal. such as [1,1,0] and [0,1,1]

Answer (score 1):

The rank of a matrix can be defined in many ways, in particular (i) maximum number of linearly independent rows (ii)maximum number of linearly independent columns (iii)maximum size of square sub-matrix with non-zero determinant. You should be comfortable with all 3 versions and know why they are equivalent. For your immediate purpose, (ii) is the most relevant. The rank of the augmented matrix of a system of linear equations is either the same as, or one more than, the rank of the coefficient matrix. The system is consistent iff the the rank of the augmented matrix is the same as the rank of the coefficient matrix. You can take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

$A$ has $5$ rows. Let $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ be the standard basis of $ \mathbb R^3.$

Then we have

$$Ae_j=a_j$$

for $j=1,2,3.$

Can you proceed ?